# how to find Green function for boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

I know there's pretty generic algorithm, but I am stuck a bit. The initial problem is:

$$y'' - y = f(x) \quad y'(0) = 0 \quad y(\pi) = 0$$

so I do:

$$\lambda^2-1 =0 \quad \lambda_{1,2} \pm 1 $$

and:

$$y(x) = C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}$$

Conditions substitution $y'(0) = 0$:

$$y'(x) = C_1e^x-C_2e^{-x}$$

and we get

$$C_1-C_2 = 0$$

therefore we get a system:

$$\begin{cases} C_1 -C_2 = 0 \\ C_1e^{\pi}+C_2e^{-\pi} = 0 \end{cases} \tag{1}$$

EDIT after the answer:

As far as I understand Green's function is to be found in the form of:

$$G(s,x) = \begin{cases}Ay_1(x) \quad 0 \le x \le s \\ By_2(x) \quad s \le x \le \pi\end{cases} \tag{2}$$

And from there we got the system of equations (here we replace $y(x) \to y(s)$):

$$\begin{cases}By_2(s) = Ay_1(s) \\ By'_2(s) =Ay'_1(s)+1\end{cases} \tag{3}$$

That is where I am stuck, I do not know how to proceed to get the $\operatorname{G}(s)$ finally.

Answer (score 1):

You need a left and right solution, the left satisfying the left boundary condition, the right the right.

With some linear equations solving these should turn out as
$$
y_1(x)=A\cosh(x)~~\text{ and }~~y_2(x)=B\sinh(\pi-x)
$$
These then get combined into a solution to
$$
y''-y=\delta(x-s)
$$
meaning that
$$
y_1(s^-)=y_2(s^+)~~\text{ and }~~y_1'(s^-)+1=y_2'(s^+).
$$
This again is simple linear equation solving to find the appropriate $A,B$.

Comment: but how do we get $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ exectly?

Comment: What do you mean? The boundary conditions determine these solutions up to a constant, and the last set of equations fixes those constants.

Comment: I expanded my post after reading your answer + reading some books examples, I am not sure that the system that I have after $y(x) \to y(s)$ is correct, plus as far as I understand I have to find either $C_1$ or $C_2$ before solving the final system to find $A$ and $B$?